# Проблема с setAttribute() / removeAttribute при выборе элемента через radio-button

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Имеем:

1. два radio-button'a
2. две кнопки: добавить строку/удалить строку
3. и две таблицы.

С помощью radio-button'a выбираем таблицу у которой будем добавлять/удалять строку. Если количество строк таблицы == 2, то кнопке "удалить строку" ставим атрибут disabled. Если кол-во строк == 10 то кнопке "добавить строку" ставим disabled.

Проблема в том, что если у одной таблицы стоит атрибут disabled, то при выборе другой таблицы (меняем radio-button) disabled сохраняется.

Итого 2 вопроса:

1. Как это исправить, чтобы disabled добавлялся только для той таблице кол-во строк которой соответствует условию, а для другой таблицы (если условию не соответствует) кнопки добавить/удалить должны быть активными.
2. При добавлении строки клонируется последняя строка таблицы и если в элементах этой строки есть некое значение, то оно тоже копируется. Как этого избежать (чтобы даже если у элемента последней строки есть значение, то строка с элементов добавлялась без значения)?

```js
var table1 = document.getElementById('radio-table1'),
  table2 = document.getElementById('radio-table2'),
  addRow = document.getElementById('addRow'),
  removeRow = document.getElementById('removeRow');


// выбираем таблицу

function getTable() {
 return (table1.checked) ? document.getElementById('table-one') : document.getElementById('table-two');
}


// добавляем строку

addRow.onclick = function() {
 var table = getTable(),
   lastRow = table.querySelectorAll('tr:last-child')[0];
 
 this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('disabled');
 
 if(lastRow.parentNode.children.length == 10) return;
 
 lastRow.parentNode.insertBefore(lastRow.cloneNode(true), null);
 
 if(lastRow.parentNode.children.length == 10) {
  this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 } 
}


// удаляем строку

removeRow.onclick = function() {
 var table = getTable(),
   lastRow = table.querySelectorAll('tr:last-child')[0],
   parentLastRow = lastRow.parentNode;
 
 this.previousElementSibling.removeAttribute('disabled');
 
 if(parentLastRow.children.length == 2) return;
 
 parentLastRow.removeChild(lastRow);
 
 if(parentLastRow.children.length == 2) {
  this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 } 
}

// предварительная проверка количества детей таблицы

function checkTableElementsLength() {
 var tableOne = document.getElementById('table-one').querySelectorAll('tr:last-child')[0],
   tableTwo = document.getElementById('table-two').querySelectorAll('tr:last-child')[0];
 
 if (tableOne.parentNode.children.length == 2 || tableTwo.parentNode.children.length == 2) {
  removeRow.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 }
 
 
}
checkTableElementsLength();
```

```css
div { margin: 10px; }
div > * { display: inline-block; }

table { float: left; margin-right: 30px; }

table input {
 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input id="radio-table1" type="radio" name="table" checked /><label for="radio-table1">Таблица 1</label>
 <input id="radio-table2" type="radio" name="table" /><label for="radio-table2">Таблица 2</label>
</div>
<div>
 <button type="button" id="addRow">Добавить строку</button>
 <button type="button" id="removeRow">Удалить строку</button>
</div>
<table id="table-one">
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-two">
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при клике в радио-кнопку не запускается следующая проверка для кнопок добавления/удаления строк, - нужны ли для вновь выбранной таблицы ранее установленные/снятые атрибуты disabled?

Самое простое это заставить всплыть события click для тех же **addRow** и **removeRow**, примерно таким образом:

```
table1.onclick = function() {
            var eventClick = new Event('click');
            addRow.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
            removeRow.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
        }

        table2.onclick = function() {
            var eventClick = new Event('click');
            addRow.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
            removeRow.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо. А по второму вопросу есть варианты? ))

Comment: Второй вопрос как-то пропустил =) Ну, я бы положил в переменную значение для вставки, аля _var insertThis = '<tr>...</tr>'_ и вставлял бы его. Тогда всегда будет вставляться этот пустой шаблон. Если необходимо динамически рассчитываеть кол-во <td>, то перед вставкой посчитать необходимое количество на основе, скажем, последней строки выбранной таблицы, наполнить insertThis нужным количество td и вставить. Как то так...

Comment: Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Заметил один странный баг - если обеим таблицам добавить по 10 строк, а затем кликнуть по радио-баттону, то у одной из таблиц удаляется строка ... Как это вылечить?

Comment: Да, и еще вопрос - как избавиться от дублирования кода в вашем примере?

Comment: есть идеи по данным проблемам?

Comment: Может быть ты сможешь помочь - @Grundy

Comment: @Astor создал [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/85TMWQwYxDGGxOt4piLF). Единственное, что там не предусмотрено - это момент с шаблоном. Думаю, сами разберетесь =) Там же ответ на вопрос с дублированием кода и без бага.

Comment: И снова работает некорректно:
- 1-ой таблице добавляем 10 строк
- 2-ой таблице добавляем 10 строк
- у 1-ой таблицы удаляем строки 
- переходим ко второй таблице, но кнопка (удалить строку) неактивна

Comment: @Astor на 18ой строке уберите return

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43422/discussion-between-astor-and-mr-brightside).

Comment: Ответ принят. Внесите, пожалуйста в него изменения. Спасибо.